# Threading HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, threadpool, httpurlconnection

I have about 10 lists that contains location data, each list has 10.000 entries. I am starting an executerService to thread all the work.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(locationLocationList.size());

for(List<Location> locationList: locationLocationList){
    executor.execute(new TestThread(locationList));
}
```

It takes soo long to finish the work, even in 10 threads. The most expensive part seems to be the one where i open the url and connect to it. Anyone an idea how i can tune this?

```
@Override
        public void run() {
            while(isRunning){
                Gson gson = new Gson();

            Map<Integer, Data> map= new HashMap<Integer, Data>();

            for(Location location: locations){
                String data = getJSON(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                Data data= gson.fromJson(data, Data.class);
                map.put(location.getId(), data);

            }


            weatherDao.setWeatherFast(map);
            isRunning = false;
        }                       
    }

    private String getJSON(double latitude, double longitude) {
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;

        try {
            URL u = new URL("someurl"+latitude+""+longitude);
            httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            httpUrlConnection.connect();
            int status = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
           LOGGER.error("Couldnt get Data", ex);
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow:

- Store the result of `getJSON()` method based on `Latitude` and `Longitude`.
- For each call first check in the stored map if found then there is no need to call `getJSON()` method again.

I hope this will help you if `Latitude` and `Longitude` are repeating.

---

Sample code:

```
 Map<String,String> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();

 key (Latitude + "_" + Longitude) and value (data)
```

Keep in mind that `cache` is using in multi-threading.

Comment: Or better still sort the list and remove duplicates before you start.

Comment: @EJP thanks, I think `TreeMap` is a better option having `Latitude + Longitude` as key and `String` as value.

Comment: What about `HashMap<String,String>`?

Comment: Mh... every entry in my list is unique, so there is no need to check if its already inserted.

The urlConnection seems to be the slow part

Comment: It means you have 10000*10 distinct entries.

Comment: you have 10000*10 location as well.

Comment: No sorry, the Map isnt the problem. What happens in getJSON() is the slow part. 

And my map is a local variable. Is it not thread safe? I thought that just variables which are shared between threads should be synchronized.. But this variable isnt shared as my understood it. Or  am i wrong?

Comment: I am talking about the map that I suggested you to cache results but as per you. You don't have any duplicate entries then there is no meaning of my approach.